# Changes done in gridview doesn't show up in code behind

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a gridview in my aspx which is bound to data from the database. It has a checkbox. When I change the checked status from client side the changes doesn't show up in the code behind. Any idea why this happens?

```
<asp:Button OnClick="Btn_Click" CommandArgument="<%# GridViewUserList %>" runat="server" Text="Save" />
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridViewUserList" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="false" ShowHeader="true" Width="100%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="isSelectHeader" runat="server" Text="Assign" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="isAssigned" runat="server" Checked='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsAssigned") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="5%" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="top" />
            <FooterStyle Width="5%" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="top" />
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Salutation" HeaderText="User"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here is my code behind.

```
protected void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < userLicenseList.Count; i++)
    {
        var isAssigned = GridViewUserList.Rows[i].FindControl("isAssigned") as CheckBox;
        if (isAssigned.Checked != userLicenseList.ElementAt(i).IsAssigned)
        {
            //some code
        }
    }
}
```

`isAssigned.Checked` has the previous value, not the changed value.

`userLicenseList` has the data from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must bind your GridView data iside an IsPostBack check. Otherwise the checked state will be overwritten by the data bound to the GridView and you will lose all changes made by a user.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //not here
    GridViewUserList.DataSource = source;
    GridViewUserList.DataBind();

    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        //but bind data here...
        GridViewUserList.DataSource = source;
        GridViewUserList.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code to find checkbox value on button click as shown below.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
        {

            if (((CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("isAssigned")).Checked == true)

            {
                //Your logic here .
            }
            else
            {
                //Your logic here.
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: The problem is that changes made in the view doesn't appear in the code behind. It only shows the previous value.

Comment: It is reflecting the new value and checked on local system with test data.